# Why does heightForRowAtIndexPath: come before cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Almost every time I write an app for a client I have to implement some kind of 'hack' to get `UITableViewCell`s to dynamically become the right height. Depending on the content of the cells this can vary in difficulty.

I usually end up running through code that formats the cell twice, once in  `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and then again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I then use an array or dictionary to store either the height or the formatted cell object.

I've probably written and rewritten this code 20 times over the past 2 years. Why did Apple implement it in this order? It would be much more straightforward to configure the cells and THEN set the height either in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or shortly thereafter in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Is there a good reason for the existing order? Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Unless one works for Apple, there's no way to answer this definitively. One way to work with this requirement is to make your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method cache the computed value in a dictionary by `NSIndexPath`. This way your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` could call through to the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method without having to compute anything more than once.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if I understand you correctly you want me to call the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` That's genius and it worked!!

Comment: Why do you need to know the cell's height in `cellForRow...`.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't need it there, but that's where I calculate what it will be by configuring the view so it's not efficient to recreate an instance of it again just to get the height in a different method.

Comment: @centreee even if you call heightForRowAtIndex: from cellForRowAtIndex: still heightForRowAtIndex: would be called before cellForRowAtIndex:. Can you please tell how are you achieving heightForRowAtIndex: not being called before cellForRowAt?

Answer (score 8):

Best guess: `UITableView` needs to know the total height of all cells so that it can know the percentage of scroll for the scroll bar and other needs.

Comment: Great. Since I don't work for Apple it was a guess on my part, also @dasblinkenlight commented that unless one works at apple it is a guess. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in iOS 7, it doesn't have to work that way. You can now set an *estimated* height for your rows and calculate each row's real height only when that row is actually needed. (And I assume that this is exactly because people made complaints identical to yours: "Why do I have to do this twice?")

Thus you can postpone the height calculation and then memoize it the first time that row appears (this is for a simple one-section table, but it is easy to adapt it if you have multiple sections):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create empty "sparse array" of heights, for later
    NSMutableArray* heights = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.modeldata.count; i++)
        [heights addObject: [NSNull null]];
    self.heights = heights;

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40; // new iOS 7 feature
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int ix = indexPath.row;
    if ([NSNull null] == self.heights[ix]) {
        h = // calculate _real_ height here, on demand
        self.heights[ix] = @(h);
    }
    return [self.heights[ix] floatValue];
}
```

You supplied an estimated height, so all the heights are *not* asked for beforehand. You are asked for a height only before that row actually appears in the interface, either because it is showing initially or because you or the user scrolled to reveal it.

**NOTE** Also, note that if you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` the cell you get *has the correct final height* already. That is the whole point of this method (as opposed to the earlier mere `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`).

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/estimatedRowHeight

Comment: And downloadable working example project code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p424variableHeights/ch21p722variableHeights/RootViewController.m