# tableview duplicating data on back button

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating individual members in my app, and everything works well. I validate user input, store it in a local array, and then pass the data on to Firebase when I tap 'next'. The app takes me from **Step 2** to **Step 3**. So far so good.

This is what **Step 2** looks like if I load the app from scratch: [Step 2 Existing Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9UUb.png). The users are pulled from Firebase, and everything is correct.

If I add a new user, everything updates fine. I tap the 'next' button, and Firebase updates with 3 users, all with correct data, and I'm taken to **Step 3**. All is good still.

But if I tap the 'back' button in the upper left corner of **Step 3** (provided by my navigation controller), the app takes me back to **Step 2** and now a duplicate entry of the new user shows up in my tableview. Somehow a duplicate user is appended to my array. [This only shows up AFTER I click the 'back' button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUlNJ.png) It doesn't show up in Firebase, but I don't know where it's coming from. I've spent all day trying to figure this out. I'm sure it's a simple problem that I'm overlooking, but I could really use the community's help on this one.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282178/getting-duplicate-tableview-cells-after-first-time) but it didn't help me. I did some tests where I printed out `users.count` and found that on `ViewDidLoad`, the count was `0`, but on the unwind segue, the count updated to `3` when I added a new user (this was correct, because there were 3 users). But then when I went to **Step 3** and tapped the 'back' button to get back to **Step 2**, **Step 2**'s `ViewDidLoad` showed a `users.count` of `4`. I have no idea why. I'm completely stumped.

Here is my Step 2 View Controller code in its entirety:

```
class Step2VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usersTableView: UITableView!

var users = [User]()        // create variable called 'users' which is an array of type User (which is a class we created)

var firebaseUser: FIRUser!
var firebaseStorage: FIRStorage!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

var cellStyleForEditing: UITableViewCellEditingStyle = .none

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "users"

    usersTableView.dataSource = self
    usersTableView.delegate = self
    usersTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    // --------
    // Firebase
    // --------

    firebaseUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    firebaseStorage = FIRStorage.storage()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(firebaseUser.uid)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped))

    loadExistingUsers()     // check to see if there are existing users, and if so, load them into tableview
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    usersTableView.reloadData()
}


// ----------
// Table View
// ----------

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! Step2Cell
    cell.myLabel.text = users[indexPath.row].firstName
    cell.userImage.image = users[indexPath.row].photo
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        deleteUserConfirmationAlert(tableViewIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditUser", sender: users[indexPath.row])
}


// ----------
// Navigation
// ----------

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditUser" {
        let nextContoller = segue.destination as! Step2UsersVC

        // 'sender' is retrieved from 'didSelectRow' function above
        nextContoller.user = sender as? User
        nextContoller.navBarTitle = "edit user"
    } else if segue.identifier == "AddUser" {
        let nextController = segue.destination as! Step2UsersVC
        nextController.navBarTitle = "add user"
    } else {
        print("Segue Initiated:",segue.identifier!)
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToStep2VC(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let sourceVC = sender.source as! Step2UsersVC
    let updatedUser = sourceVC.user
    if let selectedIndexPath = usersTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        // Update an existing user
        users[selectedIndexPath.row] = updatedUser!
        usersTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        // Add a new user
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: users.count, section: 0)
        users.append(updatedUser!)
        usersTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        users.sort(by: {$0.birthday < $1.birthday})
        usersTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // check for at least two users
    if users.count < 2 {
        createAlert(alertTitle: "Users", alertMessage: "You have not created enough users. Please enter in at least two users.")
    } else {
        // check for at least one parent
        if numberOfParents() < 1 {
            createAlert(alertTitle: "Users", alertMessage: "You must have at least one parent. Please enter in a parent.")
        } else {
            confirmationAlert()
        }
    }
}


// ---------
// Functions
// ---------


// if users exist on Firebase, load them
func loadExistingUsers() {
    ref.child("members").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            let userPhotoUrl = dict["profileImageUrl"] as! String
            let userFirstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
            let userBirthday = dict["birthday"] as! Int
            let userPasscode = dict["passcode"] as! Int
            let userGender = dict["gender"] as! String
            let isUserChildOrParent = dict["childParent"] as! String

            let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userPhotoUrl)
            storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                let user = User(profilePhoto: pic!,
                                userFirstName: userFirstName,
                                userBirthday: userBirthday,
                                userPasscode: userPasscode,
                                userGender: userGender,
                                isUserChildOrParent: isUserChildOrParent)
                self.users.append(user)
                self.users.sort(by: {$0.birthday < $1.birthday})

                self.usersTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}

func saveUsersToFirebase() {
    for user in users {
        let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("users").child(firebaseUser.uid).child("members").child(user.firstName)
        let profileImg = user.photo
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1)      // compress photos
        storageRef.put(imageData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            // get Firebase image location and return the URL as a string
            let profileImageUrl = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
            // save user data to Firebase
            self.ref?.child("members").child(user.firstName).setValue(["profileImageUrl" : profileImageUrl,
                                                                       "firstName" : user.firstName,
                                                                       "birthday" : user.birthday,
                                                                       "passcode" : user.passcode,
                                                                       "gender" : user.gender,
                                                                       "childParent" : user.childParent])
        })
    }
}

func editButtonTapped() {
    if cellStyleForEditing == .none {
        cellStyleForEditing = .delete
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped))
    } else {
        cellStyleForEditing = .none
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped))
    }
    usersTableView.setEditing(cellStyleForEditing != .none, animated: true)
}

func deleteUserConfirmationAlert(tableViewIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    // create alert for user to confirm user deletion
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete User", message: "Are you sure you want to delete \(users[tableViewIndexPath.row].firstName)? This cannot be undone.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "okay", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // remove user from Firebase
        self.ref.child("members").child(self.users[tableViewIndexPath.row].firstName).removeValue()
        self.users.remove(at: tableViewIndexPath.row)
        self.usersTableView.deleteRows(at: [tableViewIndexPath], with: .fade)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.usersTableView.reloadData()
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func numberOfParents() -> Int {
    var parentCount = 0
    for user in users {
        if user.childParent == "parent" {
            parentCount += 1
        }
    }
    return parentCount
}

func createAlert(alertTitle: String, alertMessage: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "okay", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func confirmationAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Users", message: "You have entered in \(users.count) users. Are you finished adding family members?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "continue", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.saveUsersToFirebase()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToStep3", sender: self)
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: I have a theory, but I don't want to put it as an answer yet until I get a bit more information. Can you put a breakpoint in `loadExistingUsers()`? I wonder if it's being called again when the back button is pressed. If so, that would attach a second listener.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Inserting a breakpoint at `loadExisingUsers` stopped the page from loading. So that's no good. But you have me thinking maybe somehow the Firebase database is the culprit. What if I tried changing the `loadExistingUsers` Firebase method of `observe` to `observeSingleEventOfType`?

Comment: That will work if you don't need to listen for additional users, but won't be suitable if you need the data to update as new users are added. Also, you can try calling `removeAllObservers()` on your listeners in `viewWillDisappear()`. See this documentation on detaching listeners: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#detach_listeners

Comment: I tried `observeSingleEvent` of `.childAdded`, and the database only returned one user. So that's out. Trying `observeSingleEvent` of type `.value`, and then I'll get to trying to detatch listeners.

Comment: `observeSingleEventof: .value` didn't work. And I tried `ref.removeAllObservers()` at the end of my `saveUsersToFirebase` method. No luck. But.... I put the `ref.child("members").removeAllObservers()` at the end of my `saveUsersToFirebase` method, and voila!! It worked. Nice! So you were right. It was the observers. Kudos, and thanks!

Comment: Post your answer as the solution, and I'll vote for it.